# PHP generic template in twig. How to reuse code?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, refactoring

I'm very new to PHP. I have a several of sites in which the only difference is a token. I use `twig templating`. How can I refactor my code to don't repeat myself and make a code more correct? I assume there is a way in `twig` to create a base template and reuse that. How should it look in my case?

My file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../web/assets/css/error-templates.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="/assets/img/logo.png">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrap">  
         {# The only different is token below #}    
            ::CLOUDFLARE_ERROR_500S_BOX::
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Another file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../web/assets/css/error-templates.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="/assets/img/logo.png">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrap">  
       {# The only different is token below #}
            ::ALWAYS_ONLINE_NO_COPY_BOX::
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the answer below satisfied your needs, please accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a master template file with twig extension (eg. main.twig) containing below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../web/assets/css/error-templates.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="/assets/img/logo.png">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrap">  
         {% block BodyMain %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in your other pages, use the code below

```
{% extends "main" %}
{%block BodyMain %}
   ::ALWAYS_ONLINE_NO_COPY_BOX::
{% endblock %}
```

See reference [twig extends documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html)